# String interpolation to make a file path not working flutter

Tags: json, flutter, path

I am trying to use a defined variable that contains book name and pass it to the rootBundle like this:

```
late final String selectedBook;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedBook = widget.bookName;
    print(selectedBook);
    final String book = selectedBook.toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ', '');
    loadAsset(book);
  }


Future<void> loadAsset(String book) async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/json/$book.json');
    final data = await json.decode(response);
      final secondLastIndex = data.length - 2;
      final chapterNumbers = data[secondLastIndex]['chapterNumber'];
      print(chapterNumbers);

      return chapterNumbers;
  }
```

but there is an error: Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: "assets/json/peter
notice it only picked up the path upto the $book, the .json is not included. when i try making the path at initState like this:

```dart
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedBook = widget.bookName;
    print(selectedBook);
    final String book = selectedBook.toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ', '');
    final filepath = "assets/json/$book.json";
    print(filepath);
    loadAsset(book);
  }
```

it also prints out as: assets/json/peter
instead of the expected: assets/json/peter.json
(assuming the book was peter)
also tried doing so:

```dart
final filepath = 'assets/json/' + book + '.json';
print(filepath);
```

it still prints out: assets/json/peter instead of assets/json/peter.json

the full output where ive printed the book alone, filepath alone and the error looks like this:

```
I/flutter (29955): exodus
I/flutter (29955): assets/json/exodus
E/flutter (29955): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: "assets/json/exodus
E/flutter (29955): The asset does not exist or has empty data.
E/flutter (29955): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:331:9)
E/flutter (29955): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29955): #1      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:90:27)
E/flutter (29955): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (29955): #2      _ChaptersState.loadAsset (package:bible/screens/chapters.dart:35:29)
E/flutter (29955): <asynchronous suspension>
```

instead of calling out the book dynamically and call it statically eg

```
final String response = await rootBundle.loadString("assets/json/peter.json");
```

this seems to work, but not the dynamic way.

Comment: This is quite clearly not a problem with string interpolation, as you already proved by trying to manually concatenate the strings together and seeing the same result.  Is `Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: "assets/json/peter` the *complete* error message?  If so, note that there is no closing quotation mark in the error message.  Your `book` string almost certainly is not simply `"peter"` and instead probably contains some non-printable character that is causing the string to not be printed as expected.

Comment: i have updated the question with the full output. kindly check it out

Comment: Again, note the missing closing quotation mark.  Try inspecting the byte data of `book`.  If you don't have or know how to use a debugger, then doing `print(book.codeUnits)` would be helpful.

Comment: this is what `print(book.codeUtils)` output:
`I/flutter (  801): [103, 101, 110, 101, 115, 105, 115, 13]`
i don't know exactly what this means.

Comment: 13 is probably a new line character.  Focus on how you are getting the value for the book - not the code that you are showing here.

Comment: This solved it. seems 13 was a problem. i used the `trim()` method to remove any leading or trailing whitespace. so `final String book = selectedBook.toLowerCase().trim();` prints out as `assets/json/exodus.json` . thank you very much. you can put this as the answer and I'll mark it.